# DLL will not be loaded due to errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll

I am getting this error

`Assembly ‘Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll’ will not be loaded due to errors: Reference has errors ‘Google.GData.Client’.`

Our project was running on Unity 2018.1, and I am testing it on 2018.3.5f1. After doing some adjustments for the upgrade, I noticed that some of our custom `MenuItem` went missing and guessed that it's probably because of this error.

I have been searching about this since yesterday but had no luck finding the right solution. Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Try to close Unity, delete the `Library` folder, open Unity and let it recompile. Actually the only folders really needed are `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` (maybe `Packages` and `PackageManager`) everything else you can safely delete and Unity will recreate them on the next start. (You might have to switch to the correct Plattform after that again)

Comment: I already tried that yesterday. I'm still having the same problem. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I found some old libraries that are not used by our project anymore. In Unity 2018.3.x, .NET 3.5 is label as deprecated. For those who may encounter the same problems do the following:

1. Look for .dll files that targets .NET 3.5.
2. Either delete them, or update them.
3. Reopen Unity